# How to programmatically stop workflows in Dynamics 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to stop all running workflows associated to an incident (and those with a name that begins with "Auto_").

However, I can't seems to find any documentation on how to stop workflow programmatically and I can't find how they are stored in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes via: http://kelvinshen.blogspot.com/2011/09/cancelling-workflows-via-sdk.html

```
Entity workflowToCancel = new Entity("asyncoperation");

workflowToCancel.Id = workflowID;
workflowToCancel["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(3);
workflowToCancel["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(32);

myCRMService.Update(workflowToCancel);
```